# how to take away a number each time i click JButton

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

So basically i need to be able to click a button, and each time its clicked it takes away 10 from 100. so after 10 clicked it should display 0.

```
    public class numberclass{
    public String numbermethod() {
    int number = 100;

    String result = Integer.toString(number);

    return result;
    }
}

//part of swing class below

String numberString = numberclass.numbermethod();

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            textArea.append(numberString);

             }
        }
    });
```

obviously as it stands it only displays 100 in the text field upon a click. I have tried many ways to make this work, but i feel like i'm missing something crucial. i have tried to google this basic, basic problem, however i seem to not be able to word it correctly.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by subtracting something from something.  Now, there's any number of ways you might achieve this, but lets start by using a method and maintain the class encapsulation...

```
public class NumberClass {

    private int number = 100;

    public void update() {
        number -= 10;
    }

    public String numbermethod() {
        String result = Integer.toString(number);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then update the text to be displayed

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        numberClass.update();
        String numberString = numberClass.numbermethod();           
        textArea.append(numberString);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You numbermethod() is flawed. You set number to 100 and return that value (100) as a String. It will never be something other than "100"! Move `int number = 100;` outside the method (member variable)

In your button listener add:

```
number -= 10; // or number = number - 10;
```